# Android : Problem to send(using Retrofit in Kotlin) or to receive from php a json file

Tags: php, android, json, kotlin, rx-java

I am developing and android application in Kotlin and I encounter a problem to send with 'POST' a json object.

The problem is that I take as response the following :

```
Post{username='null',pass='null',latitude=null,longitude=null,id=2}
```

As we conclude because the **id=2** in the above "message" the json data is not null but the fields are. *So the problem is that I can't properly decode and read the json data* and is seen by the above message because the username,pass,latitude,longitude are null. The php that sends the above message is the  following and I found it on the internet ( http://eosrei.net/articles/2011/12/basic-json-requestresponse-php ) and modified it.

```
<?php
if (_REQUEST['json']) {
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_data = json_decode($data , true);
    if (is_null($json_data)) {  
        $response = array(
            'username' => json_data['username'],
            'pass' => json_data['pass'],
            'latitude' => json_data['latitude'],
            'longitude' => json_data['longitude'],
            'id' => 1
            );
    }
    else {
        $response = array(
            'username' => $json_data->username,
            'pass' => $json_data->pass,
            'latitude' => $json_data->latitude,
            'longitude' => $json_data->longitude,
            'id' => 2
            );  
    }
}
else {
        $response = array(
            'type' => 'error',
            'tsagk' => 'TSAGK',
            'value' => 'No JSON value set',
            );
}
$encoded = json_encode($response);
header('Content-type: application/json');
exit($encoded);
?>
```

I also have the following APIService in my android :

interface APIService {

```
@POST("json.php")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8", "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8", "Cache-Control: max-age=640000")
fun savePost(
        @Body jsonObject: JSONObject
): Observable<Post>
}
```

Inside the MainActivity I have the sendPost :

```
fun sendPost(user: String, pwd: String) {
    writeOnDebugger("sendPost()")
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("username", user)
    jsonObject.put("pass",pwd)
    jsonObject.put("latitude",35.5)
    jsonObject.put("longitude",36.5)

    writeOnDebugger(jsonObject.toString())

    // RxJava

    mAPIService?.savePost(jsonObject)?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe(object : Subscriber<Post>() {
                override fun onCompleted() {
                    writeOnDebugger("onCompleted()")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    writeOnDebugger("onError()")
                }

                override fun onNext(post: Post) {
                    writeOnDebugger("onNext()")
                    showResponse(post.toString())
                }
            })
}

fun showResponse(response: String) {
    writeOnDebugger("showResponse()")
    if (mResponseTv?.getVisibility() === View.GONE) {
        mResponseTv?.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
    mResponseTv?.setText(response)
}
```

I have a post class :

```
class Post {

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
var username: String? = null
@SerializedName("pass")
@Expose
var pass: String? = null
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
var latitude: Double? = null
@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
var longitude: Double? = null
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
var id: Int? = null

override fun toString(): String {
    return "Post{" +
            "username='" + username + '\''.toString() +
            ", pass='" + pass + '\''.toString() +
            ", latitude=" + latitude +
            ", longitude=" + longitude +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}'.toString()
}
}
```

RetrofitClient :

```
object RetrofitClient {

private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
//    var gson = GsonBuilder()
//            .setLenient()
//            .create()
fun getClient(baseUrl: String): Retrofit? {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(/*gson*/))
                .build()
    }
    return retrofit
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, (in your php file) you are checking if there is any field with key==`json`.
But if you look closely at your `sendPost()` function, you do never add a `json` field to the body, hence the response will not be the expected one.

The **solution** could be

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject()
jsonObject.put("type", type)
jsonObject.put("tsagk",tsagk)

val body = JSONObject()
body.put("json", jsonObject)
```

and then passing the `body` value to your post request.